# aggregation to find a document by specific date

Tags: mongodb

It seems simple but I have not been able to do an aggregation that allows me to search for a document by entering a specific date.

for example I have these collections:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf2990846471279461d0a8"),
        "date" : ISODate("2020-11-26T04:05:36.314Z"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf2990846471279461d0a8"),
        "date" : ISODate("2020-11-24T04:05:36.314Z"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf2990846471279461d0a8"),
        "date" : ISODate("2020-11-23T04:05:36.314Z"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf2990846471279461d0a8"),
        "date" : ISODate("2020-11-27T04:05:36.314Z"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf2990846471279461d0a8"),
        "date" : ISODate("2020-11-25T04:05:36.314Z"),
    }
```

I want to filter the date that corresponds with `2020/11/25` (in this case it is the last collection)

what am I doing wrong?

```
collection.aggregate(
[
  {
    $match:  {
           "date": {
            $lte: new Date("2020/11/25"),
            $gte: new Date("2020/11/25")
           }
   }
 }
]
```

Desired output:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fbf2990846471279461d0a8"),
        "date" : ISODate("2020-11-25T04:05:36.314Z"),
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- set 0 time in start date and set end time in end date

```
let date = "2020/11/25";
let startDate = new Date(new Date(date).setHours(00,00,00));
let endDate = new Date(new Date(date).setHours(23,59,59,999));

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      date: {
        $gte: startDate,  // ex: 2020-11-25T00:00:00.00Z
        $lte: endDate  // ex: 2020-11-25T23:59:59.00Z
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Qyuum44gJ3)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the timestamp you have. So the trick what I did is, convert it to String and substring to 10.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      dateConverted: {
        "$dateToString": {
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          "date": "$date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      dateConverted: {
        $gte: "2020-11-25",
        $lte: "2020-11-25"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      dateConverted: 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-F_EWXiGLgg)**

Comment: thanks! I'm learning mongodb and I find this topic of aggregates interesting, I have a question, is it possible to debug at some point? something like a console.log () in javascript, sometimes I do things but I don't know what I'm doing wrong when I build an aggregation and it's worse when I don't see errors.

Comment: If you use the  mongo compass, its very useful to check the aggregations. Ang try to improve the aggregation knowledge which helps you anyways. Just showed you the aggregation way, bcs you did aggregation